# Alterar um campo destacável PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, itextsharp

Estou a trabalhar em MVC 4 e instalei o [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) para criar PDF's, até tudo bem. Mas o que estou a fazer é replicar um PDF que já existe, para preencher os respectivos campos necessários neste meu PDF criado.

Agora surge a **dúvida**:

O PDF que estou a replicar tem daqueles campos chamados de *destacáveis*, ou seja, podemos abrir o PDF e escrever nestes mesmos como se estivéssemos a editar o PDF. É possível a partir do iTextSharp abrir este mesmo ficheiro PDF, detectar estes campos e escrever nos mesmos a partir do *controller*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo, vamos entender melhor a aplicação do seu sistema... não consegui entender o que precisa, então poderemos dar uma resposta melhor.

Você terá um Formulário, ou contrato, ou algo parecido que precisa ser preenchido por várias pessoas cliente ou funcionários? Através do sistema certo?

O conteúdo desse PDF muda constantemente? São vários tipos de formulários? (Se ambas forem negativas pode-se colocar o conteúdo dele fixo no seu código ou salvar o texto em uma tabela a partir de uma tela onde o usuário que monta o formulário digite e clique em algum botão que adiciona uma lacuna e por aí vai e na hora de gerar o PDF dentro da aplicação você substitui essas Tags pelo campos.)

**UPDATE:**

Encontrei um exemplo que talvez possa lhe ajudar!

```
//Read all 'Form values/keys' from an existing multi-page PDF document
public void ReadPDFformDataPageWise()
{
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(Server.MapPath(P_InputStream3));
AcroFields form = reader.AcroFields;
try
{
for (int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, AcroFields.Item> kvp in form.Fields)
    {
        switch (form.GetFieldType(kvp.Key))
        {
            case AcroFields.FIELD_TYPE_CHECKBOX:
            case AcroFields.FIELD_TYPE_COMBO:
            case AcroFields.FIELD_TYPE_LIST:
            case AcroFields.FIELD_TYPE_RADIOBUTTON:
            case AcroFields.FIELD_TYPE_NONE:
            case AcroFields.FIELD_TYPE_PUSHBUTTON:
            case AcroFields.FIELD_TYPE_SIGNATURE:
            case AcroFields.FIELD_TYPE_TEXT:
                int fileType = form.GetFieldType(kvp.Key);
                string fieldValue = form.GetField(kvp.Key);
                string translatedFileName = form.GetTranslatedFieldName(kvp.Key);
                break;
        }
    }
}
}
catch
{
}
finally
{
    reader.Close();
}
}
```

Este e outros exemplos de como utilizar o `iTextSharp` você encontra [neste link](http://simpledotnetsolutions.wordpress.com/2012/04/08/itextsharp-few-c-examples/)

Comment: o que queria fazer era abrir um ficheiro no controller a partir do iTextSharp, e detectar os campos destacáveis que o PDF tem, para os poder preencher com dados que ia buscar a base de dados.

Comment: O que esse método faz não é varrer e recuperar esses campos?
`case AcroFields.FIELD_TYPE_TEXT:` não seria um campo editável?
Tente executar esse método em Debug e veja se os valores atribuidos à: `int fileType`, `string fieldValue` e `string translatedFileName` são satisfatórios a sua necessidade, se sim é só alterar o método ou criar outros métodos para complementar sua intenção.

Já deu uma olhada no link que lhe enviei? É em inglês mas tem muita coisa.
http://simpledotnetsolutions.wordpress.com/2012/04/08/itextsharp-few-c-examples/

Comment: Sim, já estive a ver e realmente consigo ir buscar os campos do PDF. No link que deste, tem como escrever no pfd. Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Sim, é possível! Você precisa usar a namespace `iTextSharp.text.pdf`. `camposDict` é um `IDictionary` tradicional.

Segue a implementação que uso:

```
public string PDFReplace(
               string path, // PATH do arquivo
               string arquivo, // NOME do arquivo com extensão
               object camposDict // IDictionary
               )
{
    string pathPdf = string.Empty;
    PdfReader pdf = new PdfReader(@path.ToString());
    MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream();
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(pdf, outStream);

    AcroFields fields = stamper.AcroFields;

    foreach (DictionaryEntry de in (Hashtable)camposDict)
    {
        string Key = (string)de.Key;
        string value = de.Value.ToString();

        fields.SetField(Key, value);
    }

    stamper.FormFlattening = true;
    stamper.Close();
    pdf.Close();

    string urlPasta = path.ToString().Substring(0, path.ToString().LastIndexOf("\\"));

    File.WriteAllBytes(urlPasta + "\\" + arquivo.ToString().ToUpper(), outStream.ToArray());
    return urlPasta + "\\" + arquivo.ToString().ToUpper();
}
```

**Update**

Um adendo: o `IDictionary` deve ser composto pelo nome do campo dinâmico do PDF (sim, eles precisam ser nomeados) e o respectivo valor do mesmo.

Comment: esse `camposDict` está a ser recebido na função. Que valor é que passo para lá? É o nome absoluto do ficheiro (caminho + nome do ficheiro) ??

Comment: Não, é um dicionário, use como `Hashtable` em que a chave é o nome do campo do PDF!

Comment: Pois, ai está um problema. O cliente deu-me o PDF sem pormenores. Como é que consigo saber o nome dos campos? Ando aqui à procura no foxit e não encontro nada que me diga o nome dos campos

Comment: Preenchi o formulário e exportei os dados para um `.txt`. Será que o resultado apresentado é o nome dos campos no PDF?

Resultado:
`empresa de origem 1 empresa de origem 2 empresa de origem 3 empresa de origem 4 empresa de origem 5 empresa de origem 6 LocalData Assinatura Na qualidade de tradutor públ
11 22 33 44 55 66  `

Comment: Se você abrir um PDF com títulos no Adobe PDF Reader, ele exibe! Mas para editá-los você precisaria do adobe creator ou equivalente.

Comment: Cara, não sei... Pode ser que sejam! Vale o teste!

Comment: Ao criar a `string urlPasta` obtenho o erro `Length cannot be less than zero.`. É porque?

Comment: Sua variável `path` deve terminar com barra invertida (você pode mudar de acordo com sua necessidade). Para mim era assim porque usava um caminho de rede. O propósito disso é sanitizar as barras, eu teria resolvido de forma diferente da que resolvemos quando esse código foi criado.

Comment: Sim, já acabei por corrigir. Não está é a escrever nos títulos. Estou a fazer algo do tipo:`Hashtable campos = new Hashtable(); campos[1] = "empresa de origem 1"; campos[2] = "empresa de origem 2";

                foreach (DictionaryEntry de in (Hashtable)campos)
                {
                    string Key = de.Key.ToString(); string value = "teste 1 !!!"; fields.SetField(Key, value);
                }`

Comment: Bem, como disse, suspeito que os campos devam ser nomeados

Comment: Acho que não consigo saber o nome dos campos. Vou desenhar o pdf :|